# Triangulation in Matplotlib with Provided Traingles

Tags: python, matplotlib, triangulation

I have data as follow: x, y, triangles

On MATLAB and using the trisurf function, I provide (triangles, x, y) to get the result, very straight forward.

On Matplotlib however, if I use the same data I get:

- Triangles number out of bound (if I use existing triangles)
- Strange line outside my geometry (red line) if I let tri.triangulation de decide on the triangles. (Delaunay triangulation).

maybe my problem requires different approach, I would be happy if someone can direct me to a better solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dlel = pd.read_fwf('HSH_Calculation.LEL')
dlnd = pd.read_fwf('HSH_Calculation.LND')
dt = pd.read_fwf('HSH_Calculation.HTD')

xy = np.asarray(dlnd.iloc[:, 3:5])

x = xy[:, 0]
y = xy[:, 1]
triangles = np.asarray(dlel.iloc[:, 1:4])
# triang = tri.triangulation(x,y)
triang = tri.Triangulation(x, y)


plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
# plt.triplot(x, y, triangles, 'go-', lw=1.0)
plt.triplot(triang, 'go-', lw=1.0)
plt.title('triplot of user-specified triangulation')
plt.xlabel('Longitude (degrees)')
plt.ylabel('Latitude (degrees)')

plt.show()
```

[Calculation files][1]

[image: output]

[1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HPlSu6HYzVpIgtT7y_maeNESUa5y1WW9/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YKFxfkU1iIkEfXPs9nZd6f-STkJNqT2Q/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1njxGiYqucUv4YyhY6H0U35lfuN2_zPfw/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Finally discovered that this is not the right way to approach the problem.
I had to use patches.Polygon to create separately each triangle.
I later added a color map as per the function output (z).

super happy that it worked!